# Magento 1 Cache folder is not accessible when using shell command

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, permissions

I'm having a problem with getting a shell command to clear a specific product cache because the permissions in the cache folder are strictly restricted to www-data. For example, folder `/var/cache/mage--a` files are like these:

```
-rw-------  1 www-data www-data 7646 Mar  4 11:20 mage---c54_PRODUCT_CACHE_123
-rw-------  1 www-data www-data  184 Mar  4 11:20 mage---internal-metadatas---c54_PRODUCT_CACHE_123
```

So when the shell command runs, it calls `Mage::app()->cleanCache('PRODUCT_CACHE_123')`, which triggers down to `_fileGetContents` function defined in `lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php` and it's unable to open the meta file in `/var/cache/mage--a` due to the permissions listed above.

Does anyone have a suggested fix for this?

Comment: Which user executes the shell command? Let the user www-data execute the shell command or root.

Comment: What do you have when you enter `whoami` ?

Comment: @HelgeB thanks for the suggestion, the shell command is run by cron so i believe it's not www-data

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Redis for caches instead. This helped solve the problem as i don't need to set up file permissions for the cache folder anymore.